# How to use rescale in predict

Tags: r, machine-learning, image-processing, keras, predict

I train my Keras model under R with 4 classes of images storage in folders. I use train_datagen and rescale:

```
train_datagen = image_data_generator(
  rescale = 1/255,
  rotation_range = 40,
  width_shift_range = 0.2,
  height_shift_range = 0.2,
  shear_range = 0.2,
  zoom_range = 0.2,
  horizontal_flip = TRUE,
  fill_mode = "nearest"
)
```

Then I use my model to predict a new image using the following code and the results are really bad even if my training give me an accurancy of 80%.

```
model <- load_model_hdf5("my_model.h5")
img <- image_load(image, target_size = c(64,64))
x <- image_to_array(img)
x <- array_reshape(x, c(1, dim(x)))
x <- imagenet_preprocess_input(x)
predictions <- model %>% predict(x)
```

I would like to know if I need to rescale my new image as I did for training or do I have to train without rescale ? How to implement rescale in predict ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In test phase, you should apply the same pre-processing steps on your data which you have used in training phase. Since you have only used re-scaling in training phase, you only need to do that in test phase. Therefore, remove `x <- imagenet_preprocess_input(x)` and instead use `x <- x / 255.0`.